# How can I listen for global mouse events in Elm 0.19?

Tags: onclick, mouseevent, elm

To listen for mouse events on an HTML element in Elm, we can use [Html.Events.onClick](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#onClick). However, I want to listen for mouse clicks anywhere on the document.

I found the `elm-lang/mouse` package that provides [Mouse.clicks](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/mouse/latest/Mouse#clicks) which seems to be intended for just that. On Elm 0.18, it can be installed like this:

```
elm-package install elm-lang/mouse
```

And imported like this:

```
import Mouse exposing (clicks)
```

But on Elm 0.19, the command

```
elm install elm-lang/mouse
```

does not work:

> The following packages do not work with Elm 0.19.0 right now:
>
> ```
> elm-lang/mouse
> ```

No reason is given in the console output. The [documentation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/mouse/1.0.1/) does not seem to indicate anything about this module has changed with version 0.19.

How can I install the module? Or alternatively, how can I use Elm's standard library to listen for mouse clicks globally (on the document)?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is explicitly off-topic on SO. See [help/on-topic]. Instead you should ask about how to accomplish a specific programming task. It is very unlikely that there will be some package that matches what you want exactly. And if we don't know what you actually want to accomplish, we can't make proper recommendations.

Comment: The `mouse` package is in `elm-lang`, and can be considered part of the Elm standard library. It is not an external library, and in fact no external libraries are needed to solve this problem. The package has just been (pretty much silently) merged into another `elm-lang` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package has been [merged](https://github.com/elm-lang/mouse) into elm/browser.
So rather than `Mouse.clicks`, you now use `Browser.Events.onClick`.
See the documentation for the browser package [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Events#mouse).

To retrieve the mouse position, use [Json.Decode](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode):

```
import Browser.Events exposing (onClick)
import Json.Decode as Decode

type alias Msg =
    { x : Int, y : Int }

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    onClick
        (Decode.map2 Msg
            (Decode.field "pageX" Decode.int)
            (Decode.field "pageY" Decode.int)
        )
```

For other attributes, see the documentation on [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

Quick online demo for [click](https://ellie-app.com/6tMJqCr8CYva1) and [move](https://ellie-app.com/6tMKmpfmdKKa1).

Comment: Can I take the position of the Mouse?

Comment: @Dragno You can subscribe to eg click or move events, and get the position (among other things) from the MouseEvent. I have added a working example to my answer.